# how to simplify recipe-sysroot-native

Tags: yocto

the directory **recipe-sysroot-native** takes 200M+ disk space, I find it exists in every WORKDIR and I think they all have the save contents. It's a waste of disk space to have so many copy, and it may slow down the build time. Could it just be placed in a fixed place and every WORKDIR accesss it through symbol link??

Comment: Add `INHERIT += rm_work` in your `conf/local.conf`. See this answer for more details, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831011/2689839

Comment: It should be `INHERIT += "rm_work"`

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but that is not what i want. I am not attempt to clean the source file after build, I want all the recipes share the same recipe-sysroot-native, but not copy it to the WORKDIR every time. I have 100+ recipes in my project, and i'll have 100+ recipe-sysroot-native copy in each WORKDIR, I don't think it's wise to do so.

Comment: Previously yocto used common path `tmp/sysroots/x86_64` for this purpose. But this was change a while back to use this recipe specific. Assume you have a recipe A which depends on `python-native`, then yocto populates it for the recipe A in `recipe-sysroot-native`. The same thing applies for `recipe-sysroot`. Yes, you have cross compiler and all toolchains installed in every recipes + recipe specific depends. So this was done with reason AFAIK. Am not sure still the common place can be achieved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned here in [staging.bbclass](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-staging), the files in `recipe-sysroot` and `recipe-sysroot-native` are not copies always. Yocto tries to create hard links to actual file (i.e. only increasing the reference count to the file).

So all the files in `recipe-sysroot` and `recipe-sysroot-native` are hard links referring to one source file in your disk. So there isn't any duplicate space occupied on your disk.

[Here](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/staging.bbclass#n541) you can see the actual implementation of the `staging.bbclass` where it tries to create hard links and if not allowed, then it makes a copy.

You can always check it using `ls -i` to see the reference count of the files.

Below text is copied from yocto mega meanual,

> The second stage addresses recipes that want to use something from
>   another recipe and declare a dependency on that recipe through the
>   DEPENDS variable. The recipe will have a do_prepare_recipe_sysroot
>   task and when this task executes, it creates the recipe-sysroot and
>   recipe-sysroot-native in the recipe work directory (i.e. WORKDIR). The
>   OpenEmbedded build system creates hard links to copies of the relevant
>   files from sysroots-components into the recipe work directory.
>
> Note: **If hard links are not possible, the build system uses actual
>   copies.**